# SparkSQL - the performance of isIn() compared to multiple comparisons

Tags: performance, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

In a SparkSQL program, running on about 600 million rows, I need to filter the results according to the output from running UDF on one of the columns. Which of the following would perform better?

**Option A**

```
val result = myDataframe
        .filter((callUDF("getPrice", $"product") equalTo 1) || (callUDF("getPrice", $"product") equalTo 5))
```

**Option B**

```
val result = myDataframe
        .filter(callUDF("getPrice", $"product").isIn(1,5))
```

`product` is a String, and `getPrice()` reads from an in-memory graph DB.

Instinctively, I'd say that running the UDF only once would be better, but I have no idea what are the implications of running `isIn()`.

Would you agree with my claim?

Answer (score -2):

I don't have a lot of experience with Spark Sql but I just did joins between millions of rows of data, one with isin and then again with equalsto.  The equalsto performed much better.  For my experiment the isin took about 2-3hours, while the equalsto ran in about 30min.